# Remove text thats inside [quote] tags

Tags: php, bbcode

How could I remove everything thats inside the [quote][/quote] tags? What function should I look into? I dont want nested quotes

Consider this message:

```
[quote=Killer ed]
Ställbergsjätten ska ha varit över 220 cm lång, haft skostorlek 62 och vägt minst 160 kg.     Han ska ha ådragit sig en svår ryggskada när han räddade livet på sju män från en fallande     bergvägg i gruvan. Han ska då ha hållit emot denna vägg med sin egna rygg. Efter denna olycka var han “enbart” 213 cm lång.
[/quote]

Möjligen hade Grängsbergsjätten akromegali, dvs överproduktion av tillväxthormon[källa behövs]. Vad som dock talar emot detta är att folk som lider av akromegali ofta blir svaga, något som uppenbarligen inte drabbade Ställbergsjätten.
```

### Edit

This worked (but it i get an unwanted break/newline):

```
preg_replace('~\[quote=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/quote\]~is', '', $text);
```

Comment: those aren't valid bbCode tags. `[quote=Killer ed[/quote]`

Comment: Are you sure this is PHP code??? Maybe you are using some kind of wordpress shortcode? Please clarify your question as you might mean that your code may be a string in a variable and then an answer could be to use a function with str_replace and a regex.

Comment: @amaster507 no but its for php, its bbcode

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to support nested codes then you can use a regular expression. Look at [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace).

If you do need to support nested codes then you can write a simple parser.

<s>I'd</s> Dave Chen would recommend looking at [`bbcode_create`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bbcode-create.php) as well.

Comment: I got it please see my edit. But this replaces it with a newline/break. any idea how i can get rid of that?

Comment: It replaces it with an empty string. There is likely some whitespace remaining around the part you removed. If your string is `1\n2\n3` and you replace `"2" by ""` then you will get `1\n\n3` not `1\n3`. Match trailing (or leading, your pick) whitespace to remove it.